# What is the significance of a semicolon at the end of SQL*Plus commands?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

Some statements like create table, insert into etc take a semicolon at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE employees_demo
    ( employee_id    NUMBER(6)
    , first_name     VARCHAR2(20)
    , last_name      VARCHAR2(25) 
         CONSTRAINT emp_last_name_nn_demo NOT NULL
    ) ;
```

while others like

```
set echo on
connect system/manager
```

go through without the semicolon as well.

What is the reasoning behind this? How can I decide myself where to put the semicolon and where not?

Comment: +1 To make things more confusing, you can use / on the following line instead of the ; in some cases.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Commants to the local instance execute on return. Multi-line commands to the server execute on semicolon**

Special commands as detailed in the [SQL*Plus manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm) are the only ones that do not accept semi-colons. Wheras [SQL Commands](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/toc.htm) must end with a `;` in order to be parsed by the server.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of a command is the same as a GO statement at the end of a command executed in OSQL/SQLCMD in Sql Server. It's the sign the command will be parsed and executed.

Answer (score 7):

When you're entering an SQL statement into SQL*Plus, it needs to know when you're done with it, especially if the command spans multple rows. Therefore, it requires a *terminal character* character which can be set with the `set sqlterminator`. By default, this character is the semicolon:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from
  3  dual;

D
-
X
```

Now, changing this terminal character to a `#`:

```
SQL> set sqlterminator #
SQL> select *
  2  from
  3  dual#

D
-
X
```

The SQL statement was ended (end executed) with a `#`.

You ask: why was `set sqlterminator #` not followed by a semicolon? Answer, because this is not an SQL statement. Statements that relate to SQL*Plus and its behaviour, output, connection asf (such as `set echo on` and `connect system/manager`) are not SQL statements and are therfore entered without the semicolon.

What has this to do with the `/`?

When you entered an SQL statement, SQL*plus filled something what it calls a buffer. This buffer can be shown with the `list` command:

```
SQL> list
  1  select *
  2  from
  3* dual
SQL>
```

(Note: I only entered *list*, the rest is returned)

The `/` now executes what is currently in the buffer. Lets try that:

```
SQL> /

D
-
X
```

As can be seen, the same query is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon is the [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) for the SQL parser, whereas commands that are executed within SQL*Plus are executed immediately anyway. As an analogy, compare the semicolons in a C program to the commands entered into the shell.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that the general SQL parser shares a lot in common with the general javascript parser, in that it would like a semicolon after every appropriate place, but it's not required except in certain circumstances. When I was taught to write SQL, I was told a semicolon was part of the language, not an extra operator we could ignore.